# How to output variable value if referenced environment variable is greater than 0?

Tags: batch-file

I have currently this (or its equivalent):

```
set strength+=0
if strength+ GTR 0 echo Strength Boost:            %strength+%
```

I have also tried

```
set strength+=0
if strength+>0 echo Strength Boost:            %strength+%
```

and

```
set strength+=0
if %strength+% GTR 0 echo Strength Boost:            %strength+%
```

and

```
set strength+=0
if %strength+%>0 echo Strength Boost:            %strength+%
```

Whenever the operation comes to the second line of code it shuts itself down. I would like it to only echo the variable and other text in the string (if that wasn't already clear).

Comment: `if %strength+% GTR 0 echo Strength Boost:            %strength+%` works. Only because you have set the variable as 0 so it doesn't echo the string out. Just change the value and see

Comment: If you read the help for the IF command you will see all the operators you can use. I also would not suggest using a + symbol as the last character in a variable name as it can be seen as an assignment operator when using SET /A

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have confused how `if` statements work. Let's break the commands down.

---

**SET**

```
set strength+=0
```

creates a variable named `strength+` with a value of `0`. It could be what you intended but it could be confused with the `set /a` arithmetic operator.

---

**IF**

To denote a variable, we wrap the variable name with percentage signs: `%strength+%`

Batch file doesn't support using `>` and `<` as comparison operators since they also function as redirection operators. Instead, we have a few comparison operators:

```
EQU - equal
NEQ - not equal
LSS - less than
LEQ - less than or equal
GTR - greater than
GEQ - greater than or equal
```

Now your `if` statement looks like so(it's the same as the third one you showed):

```
if %strength+% GTR 0 echo Strength Boost:            %strength+%
```

Since `%strength+%` is equals to 0, it is not greater than `0` on the other side of the comparison.

Comment: Thank you, with your help and a little bit of common sense (I made a few other dumb mistakes) the code was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

```
set strength+=0
```

What it does:

Variable: `strength+`
Operator: `=` (assign a value)
Value: `0`
which would set a variable named `strength+` to a value of `0`.

What it probably should be:

Variable: `strength`
Operator: `+=`       (increment the variable)
Value: `0`
which increases the variable `strength` by `0`.

But this does only work with the `/a` switch:

```
set /a strength+=0
```

(doesn't seem to make sense at a first glance, but in fact it ensures, the variable is defined (either `0` if it wasn't defined before, or the previous value (unchanged - adding zero doesn't change a number)))

Consequently, `if %strength+% ...` doesn't make any sense, because there is no variable `strength+`. It should be `if %strength% ...` instead.